# Windows 7 Event 431, NetBT every computer name on network (Mulitpule)

Tags: wins

A user's Windows 7 laptop is throwing Event 4321, NetBT errors every two minutes. It is trying to register every DNS name on the network to its own interface. While there is a lot of discussion on single instances of this I have never seen it do it for every computer name in the network.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds fancy.. any of these help: http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=4321&eventno=1822&source=NetBT&phase=1 ?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem - getting this in my event log: The name "MSHOME         :1d" could not be registered on the interface with IP address 192.168.1.5. The computer with the IP address 192.168.1.30 did not allow the name to be claimed by this computer.

(MSHOME is the name of my workgroup, and 1.30 is the a Win2K3 server running Windows Home Server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was caused due to a configuration problem on the clients computer, oddly enough I couldn't replicate it but after a clean install it's been resolved.